# In an ARM device tree file, what do the three interrupt values mean

Tags: c, linux, arm, interrupt, device-tree

A device tree source for a typical ARM device would have the interrupt-controller section:

```
interrupt-controller@f8f01000 {
    compatible = "arm,cortex-a9-gic";
    #interrupt-cells = <0x3>;
    interrupt-controller;
    reg = <0xf8f01000 0x1000 0xf8f00100 0x100>;
    num_cpus = <0x2>;
    num_interrupts = <0x60>;
    linux,phandle = <0x3>;
    phandle = <0x3>;
};
```

The property `#interrupt-cells` defines the size of the tuple for registering an interrupt. Therefore, when defining a device, three integers have to be defined to specify an interrupt and its properties.

```
ocmc@f800c000 {
    compatible = "xlnx,zynq-ocmc-1.0";
    interrupt-parent = <0x3>;
    interrupts = <0x0 0x3 0x4>;
    reg = <0xf800c000 0x1000>;
};
```

The question is, what do each of the three values stand for? So, what does the line `interrupts = <0x0 0x3 0x4>;` mean? And what offset has to be added when registering an interrupt handler for it (via `signal.h`/`csignal` with `signal(<signal id>, <function name>);`)

Comment: Have you seen this page? [link](http://billauer.co.il/blog/2012/08/irq-zynq-dts-cortex-a9/)

Comment: No I had not, but it does not give a clear answer. One of the comments though led me to a [page](http://xillybus.com/tutorials/device-tree-zynq-4) that describes it properly, even clearing up confusion about 0x0 being used for shared peripheral interrupts (SPI) even though in documentation it is defined as the opposite, non-SPI. Would you be interested in writing up an answer?

Comment: Sure.  That website looks like a better writeup.  Good find

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsing from the linked websites:

> The first number is a flag indicating if the interrupt is an SPI
>   (shared peripheral interrupt). A nonzero value means it is an SPI.
>   This impacts offsets added to translate the interrupt number (16 for SPI, 32 for non-SPI).
>
> The second number is the interrupt number.
>
> The third number is the type of interrupt: 
>   0 = Leave it as it was (power-up default or what the bootloader set it to, if it did). 1 = Rising edge.  4 = Level sensitive, active high.